# Shiny ggplot output different/wrong when using group=1

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

New to stack overflow. My apologies if this is muddled. I'm about to lose my mind over this problem..

I am trying to create a ggplot line graph that has the line colored based on a grouping variable.. so one line but with different colors.

When I run the code in the console, the graph looks as expected. However, when I run the shiny app, it seems it completely ignores the group=1 argument, and splits the groups into 2 different lines.

Here is a reprex for reference:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Testing Plotly and GGplot"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        ),

        # Show a test plot
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                    width = 7,
                    plotly::plotlyOutput("test_plot")
                )
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    #initialize dataframe
    test_data <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2022-03-24", "2022-3-25", "2022-03-29", "2022-03-30")),
                               count = c(10, 14, 8, 11),
                               week_identifier = c("0", "0", "1", "1"))
    

    output$test_plot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
        
        a <- ggplot2::ggplot(test_data, ggplot2::aes(Date, count, color = week_identifier, group =1)) +
            ggplot2::geom_line() +
            ggplot2::geom_point()
      
        print(a)
        
        plotly::ggplotly(a) %>% 
            plotly::config(displaylogo = FALSE) %>%
            plotly::config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c("select2d", "lasso2d"))
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is a known issue <https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2084>

Answer (score 0):

In your shiny app you are rendering plotly not ggplot:
Here is a separate render for ggplot:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Testing Plotly and GGplot"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    
    # Show a test plot
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        width = 7,
        plotOutput("a"),
        plotly::plotlyOutput("test_plot")
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #initialize dataframe
  test_data <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2022-03-24", "2022-3-25", "2022-03-29", "2022-03-30")),
                          count = c(10, 14, 8, 11),
                          week_identifier = c("0", "0", "1", "1"))
  
  
  output$a <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(test_data, aes(Date, count, color = week_identifier, group =1)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()
  )
  
  output$test_plot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    
   a <- ggplot(test_data, aes(Date, count, color = week_identifier, group =1)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()
    a
    plotly::ggplotly(a) %>% 
      plotly::config(displaylogo = FALSE) %>%
      plotly::config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c("select2d", "lasso2d"))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I need the plot to work with plotly, so I can click on the points. Is that possible?

Comment: You problem has not shiny. It is ploty see here <https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1153> and <https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2084>

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a new row to the data. The new row should make the first group end right where the second start.

```
test_data <- data.frame(
    Date = as.Date(c("2022-03-24", "2022-3-25", "2022-03-29", "2022-03-30")),
    count = c(10, 14, 8, 11),
    week_identifier = c("0", "0", "1", "1")
    ) %>%
    add_row(Date = as.Date('2022-03-29'), count = 8, week_identifier = '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this on the RStudio Community:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-ggplot-output-different-wrong-when-using-group-1/133059/2

There is a solution that uses geom_segment instead of geom_line:

```
a <- ggplot2::ggplot(test_data, ggplot2::aes(Date, count, color = week_identifier)) +
  ggplot2::geom_segment(aes(xend = lead(Date), yend = lead(count)))+
  ggplot2::geom_point()
```